# Mozilla Firefox shows different positions of pictures

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using Twitter Bootstrap. I have divided the page content into 4 parts - 1. is a headline (`col-sm-4`), 2.,3.,4 are pictures (`col sm-2`, `col-sm-2`, `col-sm-4`). I have made a CSS class to pull pictures down. I want them to be in one row next to the H3 headline `Obrazky:`. Every browser shows it exactly as I want except for Mozzila which puts those three images next to the whole webpage. I need to fix that.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
          <br>
         <h3>Obrázky:</h3>
    </div>

         <div class="col-sm-2 pull-down">
            <br><br>
            <img src="img/mobil.png" alt="mobil" class="img-responsive img-center">
            <p class="text-center"><strong>Zobrazení na mobilu</strong></p>
            <br>
         </div>

         <div class="col-sm-2 pull-down">
            <img src="img/tablet.png" alt="tablet" class="img-responsive img-center">
            <p class="text-center"><strong>Zobrazení na tabletu</strong></p>
            <br>
         </div>

         <div class="col-sm-4 pull-down">
            <img src="img/notebook.png" alt="notebook" class="img-responsive img-center">
            <p class="text-center"><strong>Zobrazení na notebooku</strong></p>
            <br>
         </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .pull-down {
float: none;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4">
          <br>
         <h3>Obrázky:</h3>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 pull-down">
            <br><br>
            <img src="img/mobil.png" alt="mobil" class="img-responsive img-center">
        <p class="text-center"><strong>Zobrazení na mobilu</strong></p>
        <br>
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-2 pull-down">
        <img src="img/tablet.png" alt="tablet" class="img-responsive img-center">
        <p class="text-center"><strong>Zobrazení na tabletu</strong></p>
        <br>
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-4 pull-down">
        <img src="img/notebook.png" alt="notebook" class="img-responsive img-center">
        <p class="text-center"><strong>Zobrazení na notebooku</strong></p>
        <br>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```